# Karma typings.d.ts

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

What i'm trying to do is getting data from script included in index.html. I added `typings.d.ts` file in which I declared:

```
declare var TextPatterns: {
  title: string;
};
```

Now in app.component i'm using it to set title of application and it works perfectly. Problem occurs when i'm trying to run Karma. Tests fails with message:

```
ReferenceError: TextPatterns is not defined
```

Is there any way to let Karma know about typings.d.ts? Or maybe problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables coming from an external sources in index.html using `window` property. In your spec file set `TextPatterns` this way -

```
window['TextPatterns'] = {'title': 'lorem ipsum'}
```